# How to bind angular directive with ng-repeat to Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, owl-carousel

I'm trying to make a directive out of Owl Carousel in angular using ng-repeat. I have it working in its current form. However, what I want to happen is when the base array changes, I want the carousel to reflect those changes accordingly. So if I add or remove items from the array, the carousel should add or remove those items automatically.

However, what happens in effect is when the base array data changes, ng-repeat runs and creates the div containers, and the carousel disappears.

Here's the code

main.html

```
<working-team team-members="vm.teamMembers"></working-team>
```

working-team.js

```
angular
    .module('dashboardApp')
    .directive('workingTeam', workingTeam)
    .directive('workingTeamMember', workingTeamMember)

 workingTeam.$inject = [];

 function workingTeam()
 {
   return {
    restrict:'E',
    templateUrl: 'scripts/dashboard_module/widgets/working-team/working-team.html',
    link: link,
    scope: {
      teamMembers: '='
    }
  };

  function link(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel)
  {

    scope.teamMembers;
    scope.initCarousel = init;

    function init(element)
    {
      var options = {
        autoPlay: 5000,
        items: 4,
        slideSpeed : 300,
        paginationSpeed : 300,
        rewindSpeed : 200,
      };    

      angular.element(elem).owlCarousel(options);
    }

    scope.$watch('teamMembers',function(data){
      scope.teamMembers = data;
    },true);

  }
}

workingTeamMember.$inject = [];

function workingTeamMember()
{
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: false,
    link:link
  }

  function link(scope, elem)
  {
    if(scope.$last && scope.teamMembers !== undefined){
      scope.initCarousel(elem.parent());
    }
  }
}
```

working-team.html

```
<div working-team-member ng-repeat="member in teamMembers" class="p-5">
    <div class="img-circle size-125x125 text-center pt-30 bg-default lter">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x fa-lg text-default"></i>
    </div>
    <h3>
        <strong>{{ member.user.first_name }}</strong>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how to tackle this? I've been working on it for about 5 hours now and I'm not making a lot of progress.

Answer (score 0):

After about 15 hours of trying to get to the root of this issue, I finally figured it out. There were 2 things that prevented this from working - I'll explain it in more detail below.

Here's what the final solution looks like:

main.html

```
<working-team team-members="vm.teamMembers"></working-team>
```

workingTeam.js

```
angular
    .module('dashboardApp')
    .directive('workingTeam', workingTeam)
    .directive('workingTeamMember', workingTeamMember)

 workingTeam.$inject = [];

 function workingTeam()
 {
   return {
    restrict:'E',
    templateUrl: 'scripts/dashboard_module/widgets/working-team/working-team.html',
    link: link,
    transclude: false,
    scope: {
      teamMembers: '='
    }
  };

  function link(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel)
  {

    scope.team = scope.teamMembers;
    scope.initCarousel = initCarousel;
    var options = {
      autoPlay: 5000,
      items: 4,
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 300,
      rewindSpeed : 200,
    };   
    var owl = angular.element(elem);
    var owldata;
    var currentLength;

    function initCarousel()
    {
      owldata = owl.data('owlCarousel');

      if(owldata === undefined){
        init();
      }else{
        reinit();
      }
    }

    function init()
    {
      owl.owlCarousel(options);
    }

    function reinit()
    {
      owldata.destroy();
      owl.owlCarousel(options);
    }

    scope.$watch('teamMembers',function(newTeam, oldTeam){
      if(newTeam !== oldTeam){
        if(oldTeam !== undefined && oldTeam.length > 0){
          currentLength = oldTeam.length;
        }

        scope.team = newTeam;
      }
    },true);

  }
}

workingTeamMember.$inject = [];

function workingTeamMember()
{
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: false,
    link:link
  }

  function link(scope, elem)
  {
    if(scope.$last){
      scope.initCarousel();
    }
  }
}
```

working-team.html

```
<div ng-repeat="member in team" class="p-5">
    <div class="img-circle size-125x125 text-center pt-30 bg-default lter" working-team-member >
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x fa-lg text-default"></i>
    </div>
    <h3>
        <strong>{{ member.user.first_name }}</strong>
    </h3>
</div>
```

The first issue is that once the carousel has been initialized, you either have to use the add/remove item methods associated with the object - or in my case since I was trying to refresh the entire object as a result of the ng-repeat updating, you have to destroy the carousel and then reinitialize it with the new array of data.

Once I figured this out, it worked great, and it would update anytime the array it was bound to changed. However, there was another issue that I was facing - there were a ton of artifacts that would be left over from the previous array. Things ranging from random div wrappers with strange classes to odd angular markup.

After a couple more hours, I was able to come up with a fix. I'm pretty sure this is a result of jquery and angular not playing nicely together, but here goes. Turns out that when when angular would run "ng-repeat", it would remove the items from being displayed in the DOM, but when jquery was looking inside of the element to get the children, it didn't distinguish between the elements that had been removed by angular and which ones hadn't - it grabbed everything.

So, I was able to come up with a quick fix by modifying the owl carousel source code to the following:

[image]

I'm not a huge fan of jquery, and I'm sure there's a much more "angular" approach to this, but after having spent so long trying to get this resolved, this will work for now.